# Loop through Pivot field returns non-existing values

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

I've created some pivot tables and charts for a report that needs to run weekly. Each week, I would need to show the last 20 weeks of data. Therefore, the filter at the pivot field (pvtF) needs to be updated each week. Setting Visible-property to True or False is working well.

```
'Clear Out Any Previous Filtering at this field
pvtF.ClearAllFilters
'Start loop through PivotItems
For Each sKey In pvtF.PivotItems
  If CLng(sKey) >= nDate1 And CLng(sKey) <= nDate2 Then
    ' Date1 <= Key <= Date2, so make item visible
    pvtF.PivotItems(sKey).Visible = True
  Else
    pvtF.PivotItems(sKey).Visible = False
  End If
Next sKey
```

When I loop through pvtF.PivotItems, there are values (sKey) that are not in the original dataset and not in the pivot table at all. When such a non-existing value is selected, setting the visible-property will result in an error.
Basically, I request to walk through all PivotItems in pvtF and set the Visible-property to True or False. I would think by definition, it should not be possible that I get keys that do not exist. Can anyone help me with checks that I might need to perform, to find out what causes my problem?

I already refreshed the Pivot table and checked whether the reference was still correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you refreshed the table, there might still be remembered but in the meantime missed items:

```
Dim pc As PivotCache
For Each pc In ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches
    pc.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
    pc.Refresh
Next pc
```

Comment: Great, thanks! That did the trick. I thought that manually refreshing them would be enough; apparently I was wrong. Thanks again :)